# RibbonMenuButton Binding item clicked to command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ribbon-control

I have a problem with the RibbonMenuButton. Currently I have :

```
<RibbonMenuButton Label="Meeting" Width="Auto" ToolTipDescription="Display requests on the agenda for the meeting selected" ToolTipTitle="Meeting" 
                                  LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/meeting.png"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding MeetingsAvailable}">                       

    <RibbonMenuButton.ItemTemplate>                            
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </RibbonMenuButton.ItemTemplate>                                         
</RibbonMenuButton>
```

My **MeetingsAvailable** is actually a `Dictionary<int, string>`. This code is working, the `RibbonMenuButton`is well displaying each `Value` of the dictionnary.

Now I'm trying to get back the `Key` of the `MenuItem` which has been clicked. My idea was to use a `ICommand` in my ViewModel and to bind an event to this command. But I don't really know how to get the event corresponding to clicking an Item in the `RibbonMenuButton`

Do someone have already did that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I have no idea how to deal to bind the "I clicked on an item" to a specific command in my ViewModel ( I want to get back the Key)*... this is *not* understandable English. Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do and what problem(s) you are having.

Comment: Yes, that's more understandable... thank you. I have now removed my close vote.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the first version of the question

Comment: There's really no need to apologise... it's just that if we can't understand your question, then we can't answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can data bind an `ICommand` to a `RibbonMenuButton` using the `ItemContainerStyle` property, like this:

```
<RibbonMenuButton Label="Meeting" ItemsSource="{Binding MeetingsAvailable}" ... >
    <RibbonMenuButton.ItemTemplate>                            
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </RibbonMenuButton.ItemTemplate>
    <RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.NameOfCommand,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Views:View}}}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Key}" />
        </Style>
    </RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>                                         
</RibbonMenuButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a command in your VM to which you can bind. Then you have to do a binding of the key of your dictionary to the command parameter so you can use it inside your commandfunction. Maybe you have to create an additional Button inside your DataTemplate.